# Image not getting displayed in imageview after loading from internet

Tags: android, android-glide

Here is my code where I used Picasso as well as glide library, but the image did not get displayed in the `ImageView`. I even tried HTTP method, didn't work

```
String icon = pojo.getCurrent().getWeather().get(0).getIcon();
String iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png";
Log.v("AAA",iconUrl);
//Picasso.get().load(iconUrl).resize(20,20).centerCrop().into(weatherImage); 
Glide.with(requireActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(iconUrl).into(weatherImage);
```

I also added the dependencies

this is the layout file

```
  <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/shape"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/id_weather_refresh"
           android:layout_width="30dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_baseline_refresh"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/id_temperature"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:fontFamily="casual"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="-:-/-:-"
                        android:textColor="#040404"
                        android:textSize="34sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/id_envType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                        android:text="---------"
                        android:textColor="#716F6F" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/id_weatherImage"
                        android:layout_width="110dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

I have posted an image of what's happening, actually it has to download the image from internet and display it there, but instead it's not displaying anything.

This is the [URL](https://openweathermap.org/img/w/04d.png) of the image

The error message

```
2022-05-11 17:06:31.754 12117-12117/com.example.clothme I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to openweathermap.org not permitted
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadDataWithRedirects(HttpUrlFetcher.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:56)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.startNextOrFail(MultiModelLoader.java:164)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onLoadFailed(MultiModelLoader.java:154)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.HttpUrlFetcher.loadData(HttpUrlFetcher.java:62)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:100)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNextLoad(SourceGenerator.java:70)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:63)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:279)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:393)
2022-05-11 17:06:32.362 12117-16853/com.example.clothme I/example.clothm: Waiting for a blocking GC Instrumentation
2022-05-11 17:06:35.370 12117-16853/com.example.clothme I/example.clothm: Waiting for a blocking GC Instrumentation
2022-05-11 17:06:35.379 12117-16853/com.example.clothme I/example.clothm: WaitForGcToComplete blocked Instrumentation on ProfileSaver for 9.615ms
```

Comment: Check the verbose logs see if glide is throwing any error .

Comment: its throwing error, ill post the error message

Comment: how to resolve that error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: I think this topic will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I refered to the links and tried the first option i.e changing http to https and it worked. Thank you once again! @ADM and jpsf

Comment: @Atharv changing http to https is not always works, here's an example [URL](http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/peaceful-t2.jpg) with **HTTP** and the same [URL](https://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/peaceful-t2.jpg) but with **HTTPS**, as you can see here, the **HTTPS** url is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your **Application Tag** in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

> Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is
> disabled by default. So all requests from http protocol will no longer accepted